# what will happen if we contract an element in a uniform matroid?

Tags: graph-theory, order-theory, lattice-orders, algebraic-combinatorics, uniform-matroids

Are the parallel elements in a matroid just behaving like loops? If so, why?

For example, in $U_{2,3}$ if we contract an element what will happen? In $U_{2,2}$ if we contract an element what Will happen? In $U_{2,5},$ if we contract an element what will happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An element $e$ in matroid is a loop if $r(e) = 0$ (this is a definition). Two non-loop elements $e, f$ in a matroid are set to be parallel if $r(\{e, f\})=1$. The unifying concept here is that both loops and a parallel pair are circuits, i.e., minimal dependent sets. In other words, they are both sets of cardinality one more than their rank. If you are familiar with graphs, the above translates to loops are loops in the graph sense, parallel elements are parallel edges, and both are cycles.

In general, for the uniform matroid $U_{m,n}$ and a set $T$ of $t$ elements,

$$U_{m, n} / T \cong \begin{cases}U_{0, n-t}, & \text { if } m \leq t \leq n \\ U_{m-t, n-t}, & \text { if } t<m .\end{cases}$$

So contracting an element in $U_{2,3}$ yields $U_{1,2}$, contracting an element of $U_{2,2}$ yields $U_{1,1}$, and contracting an element of $U_{2, 5}$ yields $U_{1,4}$. This can also be seen by the definition of contraction, or pictorially, where contraction can be interpreted as a form of projection operation, as outlined in James Oxley's Matroid Theory book, chapter 3.

Comment: " the above translates to loops are loops in the graph sense" can you clarify this line please?

Comment: You can obtain a matroid $M(G)$ from a graph $G$ called the cycle matroid, whose independent sets are subsets of $E(G)$ that do not contain cycles. In such a matroid, a matroid loop corresponds to a graph loop (an edge where both ends are the same), and parallel elements of $M(G)$ are parallel edges of $G$, etc.

Comment: But does not contraction of $U_{2,3}$ gives us parallel elements in the sense of fig. 1.8 in Oxley?

Comment: Indeed, as stated above, $U_{2,3}$ becomes $U_{1,2}$ which is a pair of parallel elements. Drawn as a picture of a matroid this could be two points right next to each other. Additionally, $U_{1,2}\cong M(G)$ where $G$ is a graph with two vertices joined by two edges.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much .... This is definitely very helpful :)